# AngularFire v7.6: FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

after updating to angular 16 and angularfire 7.6 I now receive this error when i try to just load a simple collection.

Here the code of my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  Firestore,
  collection,
  collectionData,
  query,
  orderBy,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Functions } from '@angular/fire/functions';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CategoryService {
  colName = 'categories';

  constructor(private afs: Firestore, private afFunctions: Functions) {}

  loadCategories() {
    const colRef = collection(this.afs, this.colName);
    const q = query(colRef, orderBy('counter', 'desc'));
    const col = collectionData(q, { idField: 'id' });
    return col;
  }
}
```

And here the error i got when i try to subscribe to the observable.

> core.mjs:10592 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore
> FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Answer (score 0):

In AngularFire 7.6, the collection function expects the first argument to be an instance of Firestore or AngularFirestore. You are passing this.afs, which appears to be an instance of Firestore, but it seems that the library is not recognizing it.

You can import the AngularFirestore from AngularFire and then initialize it using AngularFirestoreModule in your app module.

import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    AngularFirestoreModule,
  ],
  // ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then inject AngularFirestore in your service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, collectionData, collection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { query, orderBy } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CategoryService {
  colName = 'categories';

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {}

  loadCategories(): Observable<any[]> {
    const colRef = collection(this.afs, this.colName);
    const q = query(colRef, orderBy('counter', 'desc'));
    return collectionData(q, { idField: 'id' });
  }
}
```

Comment: '@angular/fire/firestore' has no exported member "AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreModule", just "Firestore, FirestoreModule".
Seems like this is not working.

And when I console.log(this.afs) I got this output: Firestore {_authCredentials: __PRIVATE_FirebaseAuthCredentialsProvider, _appCheckCredentials: __PRIVATE_FirebaseAppCheckTokenProvider, _databaseId: DatabaseId, _app: FirebaseAppImpl, type: 'firestore', …}

Comment: Did you work out what the issue is? I was using the same code 2 weeks ago and it worked fine and now I have this error.

Comment: Nope, still no solution, i just went back to an older version and will upgrade later, hopefully it is fixed than